# Cowboy with an odd accent

Tags: 12-is-better-than-6

I am playing the excellent Wild West shooter *12 Is Better Than 6* and I believe that I am close to the end.

I have come across a cowboy with an extremely odd accent for 1800s America and was wondering if it was an Easter egg. What is he saying?

I know the developers are Russian and the game was translated from Russian to English so it could be that they have just missed a translation. It could also be rude so to prevent accidentally insulting people I've wrapped the image in spoiler tags.

> [image: The Odd Accented Cowboy]

**EDIT** I just found another:

> [image: Russian Cook]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's a Southpark reference.

According to Google Translate, *Черт, они убили Кенни* translate to:

> Devil, they killed Kenny

Which is similar enough to the catchprase:

> Oh my God, they killed Kenny!

Comment: AH! There is actually an English speaking cowboy a little further up that says a similar thing...